# My post api doesnt get executed , where as my get apis work fine. Trying to fire the api using postman, it keeps on sending the request

Tags: node.js, api, express, postman

I am using exrepss framework in nodejs. 
Server side code:

This is my server side code :

```
router.post('/signup', function (req, res, next){
      console.log("here i am " + request.body)

      User.findOne({ $or: [{ 'local.email': req.body.email }] }, function(err, user) {
          if (err) {
               res.json(err);
          }
          if (user) {
              if (user.local.email == req.body.email) {
                 res.json({msg:"This email is already taken."})
              }


          } else {
              var userData = new User();          
              userData.local.email = req.body.email;
              userData.local.password = req.body.password;
              userData.save()
                  .then (res.json)              
                  .catch(err => {
                      console.log(err);
                      res.status(400).json({msg:"unable to save to database"});
                  })

          }
        })
      });
```

While triggering this api from Postman , i am passing this as the body in the json format.

```
{
    "email": "qweeeee",
    "password": "1233"
}
```

Missed information:

I am also using session in my app.js to 
..

```
app.use(session({
  resave : true , 
  saveUninitialized : true,
  secret : 'keyboard cat',
  store : new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection}), //starting a new session 
  cookie : {maxAge : 180 * 60 * 1000}
}
));
```

..
I believe this has something to do with the post api not getting called. If i remove this code , my GET APIs also dose not work.

my app.js file looks like this.

...

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var expressHbs = require('express-handlebars');
var csurf = require ('csurf');
var cors = require('cors');
var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');

var mongoose = require ('mongoose');
var session = require('express-session')
var passport = require('passport');
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var MongoStore= require('connect-mongo')(session);
const https = require('https');

require('./config/passport');

var app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use('/css', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css'));


mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/shopping-cart", {
  useNewUrlParser: true
});
app.use(logger('dev'));

app.use(session({
  resave : true , 
  saveUninitialized : true,
  secret : 'keyboard cat',
  store : new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection}), //starting a new session 
  cookie : {maxAge : 180 * 60 * 1000}
}
)); 
app.use('/', indexRouter);
```

...

Comment: Make sure your `req.body` is not empty or undefined.

Comment: You're using mongodb or mongoose?

Comment: Do you have the `"here i am"` text in the log? Also, I have noticed `.then (re.json)` needs one more letter, otherwise it would be undefined, I suppose.

Comment: @gujci i already corrected the typo in the code. but stilll the issue persist. also i am not getting " here i am " in the logs.

Comment: Ok, So the whole function is not getting called. Could you post the code where you add this router to the middleware chain?

Comment: @gujci updated the code.

Comment: I really don't want to bother you with further questions. But maybe knowing the contents `./routes/index` would be helpful. I really don't see any obvious mistakes so far.

Comment: @gujci the context of ./routes/index is only that i have written my api router in index.js file which is in route folder and not in app.js directly. if this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are parsing the request body. Something like this

```
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.use(bodyParser.json());

router.post('/signup', function (req, res, next){
// access req.body here
});
```

Comment: i am already having this code in my app.js file. i dont that is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

‍ You can use this code below:

```js
router.post('/signup', function (req, res, next){

  // make sure this is not undefined
  console.log(req.body);

  User.findOne({ $or: [{ 'local.email': req.body.email }] }).then(user => {  
    if(user) {
      return res.json({msg:"This email is already taken."});
    }
    var userData = new User(req.body);
    userData.save().then(result => {
      // make sure the 
      console.log(result);
      res.send(200).json(result);
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(400).json({msg:"unable to save to database"});
    })
  }).catch(ex => {
    console.log(ex.message);
    res.status(500).send(ex);
  })
});
```

> Make sure your `req.body` is not `undefined`

‍ If your `req.body` is `undefined`, then you can use this code below in your `app.js` or `server.js`.

```js
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

I hope it can help you .

Comment: the first line in the api code is console.log , but it dosentt write anything on the console. that makes me feel that that control is not going inside the code itself.

Comment: Maybe it's because you don't call the route. Because if you call it, then you will definitely see console.log

Comment: i have configured router in app.js . moreover my GET apis are present in the same file which are getting executed as expected

Comment: Maybe you should to try the simple route. In the first line of your `signup` route, please add `res.status(200).send("Something")`. Let's to try it, it's working or not and you will know, what's wrong with this route.